# Swapping a mesh from MCS female to a custom mesh

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

I'm trying to swap a mesh from the MCS female CBJacket with a custom mesh that's supposed to be a lab coat. But it keeps turning in to a ball of spiky mesh! I made sure the avatar and armature for the custom fbx was the same as the official one but i'm not getting any where with this problem.

any help (as always) is greatly appreciated